# Presenting multiple/separate React web apps into one

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, micro-frontend

Over the course of several years we've collected a handful of React web apps, each hosted somewhere and each having their own source code repository.

Now we are looking to sort of "consolidate" these various web apps into a single place. The effort here should be minimal (we should not spend that much time or resources on this).

So im trying to find a solution that provides a great balance in the following:

- Easily maintainable
- Minimum effort in terms of resources/time spent
- Intuitive and very usable for our end-users

What would be a balanced solution?

I've considered solutions involving "micro-frontends", but they seem very complex and convoluted. Now i am considering a much simpler solution: Perhaps the good old fashion iframe.

Any thoughts / feedback / suggestion?

Comment: You can mount each app into a different mount point. You might be able to the components in a centralized single app. We cant answer this though because its kind of up to your preference. What issues have you run into while trying? Iframes might work for you if that is alright, there are pros and cons there too though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am looking primarily for a solution that does not involve IFrames (but i will try using it when all else fails). My first issue now is finding that alternate way to load/render an external url (ultimately another Reactjs app) into a panel with my primary Reactjs app.